# Element with id inside another element in jade/pug

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I use `pug`/`jade` and I have this code

```
span <span id='numClients'>0</span> clients
```

So I want it to output

```
<span><span id="numClients">0</span> clients</span>
```

and it does work, but it's not pretty jade. How do you normally do this?

I could eventually use

```
span
  span(id='numClients) 0
  span clients
```

but it's not quite the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you do it in jade/pug way.

```
span
    #[span#numClients 0] clients
```

This is called tag interpolation

Here's a documentation coming from jade/pug https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html

Hope it helps. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like this :

```
span
  span#numClients 0
  |  clients
```

Because as far as I can see, your code will end into some bracket error.

Answer (score 0):

[Jade support for inline tags](https://pugjs.org/language/plain-text.html#inline-in-a-tag)

Therefore, in this case

`span <span id="numClients">0</span> Clients`